# Dynamically add buttons to an already existing array of buttons

Tags: android, button

I am trying to create a button for each year since the person started using my app.  So in my xml document I have

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/yearScrollView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/currentYear"
            android:tag="01"
            android:text="2015"
            android:paddingLeft="8.0dip"
            android:paddingRight="8.0dip"
            android:height="24dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            >
        </Button>


    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Then I have the following code

```
private List<Button> yearButtons;
private static final int[] YEAR_BUTTON_IDS = {
        R.id.currentYear,
};
```

Then I must find out what year it is and overwrite my current button

```
        int firstYear = Integer.parseInt(year);
                      yearButtons.get(0).setText(String.valueOf(CurrentYear));
```

then in my init class I substantiate the buttons, I understand I do not need a loop for only 1 button but leaving it like this for consistency with how the months buttons work

```
for(int id : YEAR_BUTTON_IDS) {
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(id);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        yearButtons.add(button);
    }
```

Then I have some logic to find out the first year they started called yearsOfTransactions

Then I have the following loop where I try create the buttons

```
 for (int i =0; i< yearsOfTransactions; i++){
        int yearToAdd = CurrentYear-i-1;
        Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setText(String.valueOf(yearToAdd));
        yearButtons.add(myButton);

    }
```

However this is not working..

Thanks for any help

Comment: not working means?? you need to add it in your linear layout.. then it will get visible..!!

Comment: I suggest instead of taking `int[]` for ids you take `Arraylist<Integer>`.Because  You can not modify array size after it is created once..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making slight modification in your code :

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/yearScrollView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/currentYear"
            android:tag="01"
            android:text="2015"
            android:paddingLeft="8.0dip"
            android:paddingRight="8.0dip"
            android:height="24dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            >
        </Button>


    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Now make an array of years to add (in onCreate())

```
int[] yearToAdd = {2000, 2001, 2002, 2003};
LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.button_parent);
for (int i =0; i< yearToAdd.lenght; i++){
        int yearToAdd = yearToAdd[i];
        Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setText(String.valueOf(yearToAdd));
        yearButtons.add(myButton);
        yearButtons.setOnClickListener(this);
        parentLayout.addView(myButton);
 }
```

Let me know in case of more clearation you need, hope it will help :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to add button to a linear layout. 
This is a function i use to add dynamic buttons in a linear layout.

```
public Button createButton(String label) {
    Button button = new Button(mContext);
    button.setText(label);
    mDynamicLayout.addView(button, mLayoutParam);
    return button;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add every button you create to the LinearLayout. First set and id in xml to LinearLayout. Find the view in your class and, finally, add the buttons.

```
LinearLayout container = findViewById(R.id.container);

//...

for (int i =0; i< yearsOfTransactions; i++){
    int yearToAdd = CurrentYear-i-1;
    Button myButton = new Button(this);
    myButton.setText(String.valueOf(yearToAdd));
    yearButtons.add(myButton);

   // you missed that
    container.addView(myButton);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
please try this inside your for loop

   LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_tags);

    //set the properties for button
    Button btnTag = new Button(this);
    btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    btnTag.setText("Button");
    btnTag.setId(some_random_id);

    //add button to the layout
    layout.addView(btnTag);
```